# Ordenar fecha ddmmyyyy

Tags: sql

Tengo una web que cuando ingresas muestra una tabla con distintos datos, uno de ellos es la fecha. Quiero lograr que cuando entro a la misma me devuelta esta tabla pero con la fecha ordenada.

Tengo el siguiente código

```
SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR, WHAL.Consumo.Fecha_Autoriza,(103))) as Fecha_Autoriza FROM WHAL.Consumo
    WHERE WHAL.Consumo.Nro_Documento = ? AND WHAL.Consumo.Fecha_Autoriza BETWEEN Dateadd(yy,-1,Getdate()) AND getdate()
    ORDER BY Fecha_Autoriza DESC
```

Esta tabla ahora mismo me la ordenada, pero solo me la ordenada por el día pero el mes y año no los reconoce.

PD: No están todos los datos en la consulta ya que los saque para que el codigo no quede tan extenso.

Comment: WHAL.Consumo.Fecha_Autoriza ese campo que es? y te das cuenta que esta ordenando por ese campo, no por el campo convertido no? porque los dos tienen el mismo nombre.

Comment: @gbianchi Fecha_Autoriza es un campo datetime, por mas que le cambie el nombre al as, sigue pasando lo mismo

Comment: Porque tambien tenes que cambiar el order by ;) tu order by debe ser igual al convert...

Comment: Si también intente con eso pero nada, sigue ordenando solamente por el día y no por el año,mes,dia

Comment: Podrias mostrar los datos, todos los intentos que hiciste, y la salida que estas obteniendo?

Answer (score 0):

En SQL Server, cuando le pones un alias a una columna, puedes incluir ese alias en la clausula `order by` (OJO, que solo conozco este comportamiento en SQL Server).

Eso está creando una confusión en la manera en la que el motor interpreta tu consulta y lo que tu quieres indicarle al motor, ya que el motor está ordenando por la cadena de texto y no por el campo `fecha` subyacente, ya que se llaman igual. Por eso es que te da la *sensación* que ordena por el día, sin tomar en cuenta mes y año. En realidad está ordenando la cadena de texto y eso es normal.

Para que ordene por la fecha, indica el campo calificado, lo cual eliminará esta ambigüedad:

```
SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR, WHAL.Consumo.Fecha_Autoriza,(103))) as Fecha_Autoriza
  FROM WHAL.Consumo
 WHERE WHAL.Consumo.Nro_Documento = ? 
   AND WHAL.Consumo.Fecha_Autoriza BETWEEN Dateadd(yy,-1,Getdate()) AND getdate()
 ORDER BY WHAL.Consumo.Fecha_Autoriza DESC
```

Finalmente, luego de haber resuelto el *problema*, me gustaría indicar que me parece mala idea darle formato a la fecha en la consulta SQL. Esto es algo que debiera resolverse a nivel de presentación de datos, pues esto te dará la flexibilidad de atender diferentes *culturas* con un mismo sistema. (En distintos países, la fecha suele formatearse de manera diferente).